# Rails: Provide param to nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, jquery-file-upload

He

I have two models in my rails application (Post, Picture)  that are associated as follows:

```
#Post model
has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, :allow_destroy => true 

#Picture model
belongs_to :post
```

In my post edit view I have two forms, so I can edit the post content as well as add pictures to the post. I use the jquery file upload plugin together with carrierwave to handle the upload process. This looks quite similar to this setup here http://tinyurl.com/aun7bl5

When I go to the post edit view the jquery file upload always shows me all pictures, because it uses the index action of the picture controller which fetches all images and renders them to json so jquery file upload can handle them. The index action looks like this.

```
def index
  @pictures = Picture.all 
  render :json => @pictures.collect { |p| p.to_jq_upload }.to_json
end
```

The post param (:id) is available to the post controller when I edit a post. I can see it with the logger. But it is not available to the index action which is nested inside of the post edit form.

Now my question is, how I can provide the index action in the post controller with the id of the post I like to edit so that I can do there something like this to filter the pictures it gets:

```
def index
  @pictures = Picture.where(:post_id => params[:id])
  render :json => @pictures.collect { |p| p.to_jq_upload }.to_json
end
```

EDIT:

```
#Post#edit view
<div class=post-well>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Reisebericht editieren</h2>
  </div>

  <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :title, :label => "Titel", :input_html => { :class => 'new-post-inputfields' } %>
      <%= f.input :body, :label => "Artikel", :input_html => { :class => 'new-post-inputfields' } %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :picture_ids, :input_html => { :id => 'post_picture_ids' } %> 
      <%= f.button :submit, :label => "Speichern" %>
    </div> 
  <% end %>

  <h4>Bilder verwalten</h4>
  <%= simple_form_for Picture.new, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
      <div class="span7">
        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
          <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
          <span>Hinzufügen</span>
          <%= f.file_field :path, multiple: true, name: "picture[path]" %>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
          <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
          <span>Upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
          <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
          <span>Abbrechen</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
          <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <!-- The global progress bar -->
        <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
          <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
    <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
    <br>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
    </table>
  <% end %>
</div> 

<script>
  var fileUploadErrors = {
    maxFileSize: 'File is too big',
    minFileSize: 'File is too small',
    acceptFileTypes: 'Filetype not allowed',
    maxNumberOfFiles: 'Max number of files exceeded',
    uploadedBytes: 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size',
    emptyResult: 'Empty file upload result'
  };
</script>

<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
      <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
          <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
          <td>
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
              <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                  <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
          <button class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
              <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-download fade">
    {% if (file.error) { %}
      <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
          <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
          <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
              <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
              <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function () {  
  // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
  completed: function(e, data) {
     console.log(data.result[0].picture_id); 
     $("#post_picture_ids").val(function(i,val) { 
          return val + (val ? ', ' : '') + data.result[0].picture_id;
     });
   }
 });

 // Load existing files:
 $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
  var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload'), 
  template;
  fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
  template = fu._renderDownload(files)
  .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
  // Force reflow:
  fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
  template[0].offsetWidth;
  template.addClass('in');
 $('#loading').remove();
 });
});
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

EDIT2: For one solution see below under @SybariteManoj answer. Another solution is to use:

```
$.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action') + '/' + $('#current_post_id').val(), function (files) {
```

in the beginning of the get function and then add a route for the pictures controller as follows:

```
get 'pictures/:id', to: 'pictures#index'
```

The index action in the pictures controller will then filter for the id parameter in this solution and looks like this:

```
def index
  @pictures = Picture.where(:post_id => params[:id])
  render :json => @pictures.collect { |p| p.to_jq_upload }.to_json
end
```

I think I prefer the full solution of @SybariteManoj so there is no need for a route and the index action loks like this now.

```
def index
  @pictures = Picture.where(:post_id => params[:post_id])
  render :json => @pictures.collect { |p| p.to_jq_upload }.to_json
end
```

Comment: Can you show us how the `pictures#index` action is being rendered in edit view. I haven't worked with jquery-file-upload yet, but as far as I can guess it is using an ajax call to `pictures#index` on page load. If this is the case, then you can pass the post id in the same ajax call.

Comment: Yes it is using ajax. The associated javascript in my post above is only showing my modifications. The rest of the javascript code theat determines the behavior you can find here. (http://tinyurl.com/d6335sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the culprit. In your javascript, `$.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action')` this is passing the value of the action attribute of the image upload form.

Try adding this line somewhere in your edit view file

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :current_post_id, @post.id, :id => 'current_post_id' %>
```

and replace this line

```
$.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
```

with

```
$.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action') + '?post_id=' + $('#current_post_id').val(), function (files) {
```

I haven't tested it but I am quite sure this should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is close to the solution but I am unfortunately not that good yet in javascript/Jquery to figure it out. So far the hidden field contains the post id now and whithin the getJSON call u pull out the value. If I do this as you suggest it, there is no picture displayed at all inside my edit form. Do you think It could help to return also the post_id of each picture via the json response?

Comment: I got it. I just hadd to add another "/" between the id and the controller call of your getJSON modification and add a route with id for the pictures controller and then filter with this param inside of the index action. Thanks!

Comment: cool.. just edit the answer with your modifications, it will be a help for others. :)

Comment: Nice now it works like charm. So both solutions work.  I will update my first post with the solutions. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are editing the post, the post `params[:id]` is available to the post controller's `update` action and not to others which is the default action call after editing the form in rails.

If you want the `params[:id]` in the `index` action then you need to either redirect to the index action after update action is called or you need to put the logic of showing the selected pictures in the update action only.

You can also create a custom action method to handle the process of showing the pictures that belongs to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your `Picture` has a foreign_key named `post_id` and you can simply use this in your `index` action to get only pictures which belong to the `Post`.

Try something like this :

```
def index
  @pictures = @post.pictures 
  render :json => @pictures.collect { |p| p.to_jq_upload }.to_json
end
```

**EDIT**

Since your pictures `belong_to` your post, you also need to modify the `new` and `create` actions so that you create a picture for your post.

One way to do that is to create a method `find_post` in your `Picture` controller, and make a `before_filter` callback like this :

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_post, :only => [:index, :new, :create]

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) unless params[:post_id].nil?
  end

  def new
    @picture = @post.pictures.new
  end

  ## Same thing for the create action
end
```

And in your view, do the same when you create you form :

```
<%= simple_form_for @post.pictures.new
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes you are right that there is a post_id. But this is not available to the index action of the picture controller which would be necessary to handle it like this right? If I do it like this I get an active record error that tells me that it can not find a post without an ID.

Comment: Hm unfortunateley even this does not work. I get an error on \@post.pictures because @post is nil then. And even if I have associations they do not show up because I think :post_id is missing at all. Schould I see the :post_id in the logger when i log the params hash?

Comment: Yes indeed you should affect a post to your picture when you create it. I'll improve my answer.

Comment: Hm well thanks for that example. This was very useful and shows me how one usually would do this. But it is still not working. I think it is related to the way how the images are displayed and handled in the nested views. Jquery does an ajax call to the pictures controller index method and so it gets all the pictures. Then it reloads the parts of the page with the images. SO my pictures controller never gets the id. I think I have to change the ajax call somehow to get this working but do not know how yet. Tanks again for your help